# Phonegap/Android do "something" every 15 minutes

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm planning a new App, Android only, for a customer and for the first time I'm planning not to use java but Phonegap. I've been playing with it and looks great for almost all of my needs for this very simple project.

But there is a thing I can not figure out how to solve: I need to collect phone position from gps and send to server every 10 to 15 minutes 24/7 even when phone/app is not active (Before someone claims this is against privacy I tell you this is for a closed group of employees of my customer and I've been asked to do that this way).

I know how to do that in java by scheduling this job with Android. But so far I could not figure out how to do that with phonegap. Some plugin maybe?

Any documetation or idea will be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several cordova plugins about that, check out http://plugreg.com/search?q=background

Comment: hey, plugreg.com is really nice! With much that I searched this on google do not know how I'm just seeing this now. Thank you!